# SQLrowrowcount when updating records

Tags: oracle, plsql, sql-update

Please assist, when I have multiple update statements as such:

```
Update employees e
Set e.description = ‘Manager’ 
Where e.id = ‘1’;

Update employees e
Set e.description = ‘Supervisor’ 
Where e.id = ‘2’;

Update employees e
Set e.description = ‘Clerk’ 
Where e.id = ‘3’;

dbms_output.put_line('Updated ' || SQL%ROWCOUNT || ' rows');
```

How do I get a total count of each row which was updated as in reality I’m updating a 140 rows, even though my rows are being updated successfully I always just get a count of one as it’s just counting the last update that was done. I’m not sure how to consolidate the count for all the rows that were updated?

Comment: ROWCOUNT returns the number of rows affected by the last statement. It really depends how you generate sql and how you handle results. As an option you can use a trigger to log all changes and then use this logs.

Answer (score 1):

The `rowcount` refers only to the last statement. You can use a variable to keep track:

```
declare
  l_counter pls_integer := 0;
begin
  Update employees e
  Set e.description = 'Manager'
  Where e.id = 1;

  l_counter := l_counter + sql%rowcount;

  Update employees e
  Set e.description = 'Supervisor'
  Where e.id = 2;

  l_counter := l_counter + sql%rowcount;

  Update employees e
  Set e.description = 'Clerk'
  Where e.id = 3;

  l_counter := l_counter + sql%rowcount;

  dbms_output.put_line('Updated ' || l_counter || ' rows');
end;
```

Alternatively, here you could do a single update:

```
begin
  Update employees e
  Set e.description = 
    case e.id
      when 1 then 'Manager'
      when 2 then 'Supervisor'
      when 3 then 'Clerk'
    end
  Where e.id in (1, 2, 3);

  dbms_output.put_line('Updated ' || SQL%ROWCOUNT || ' rows');
end;
```

For both I've assumed `id` is a numeric column, so used numbers to refer to them instead of strings; and if it was a string, you had backticks instead of quotes in your example code.