# UPDATE with RETURNING not working in PL/SQL but it does separately

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have this procedure:

```
DECLARE 
    TYPE adids_table IS TABLE OF HOUSES.ADID%TYPE;
    updated_adid adids_table;
BEGIN 
    UPDATE HOUSES
    SET TRANSFERCOST = NULL
    WHERE ADID IN (
        SELECT A.ID
        FROM ADS A
            JOIN USERS U ON U.ID = A.USERID
        WHERE A.ADOPERATIONID = 1)
      AND TRANSFERCOST IS NOT NULL
      AND TRANSFERCOST != 0
     RETURNING ADID BULK COLLECT INTO updated_adid;
    
    IF updated_adid.count > 0 THEN 
         FOR i IN updated_adid.first .. updated_adid.last LOOP 
            UPDATE ADS SET MODIFICATIONDATE = SYSDATE WHERE ID = updated_adid(i);
         END LOOP;
    END IF;
END;
```

But it returns -1 updated rows if i leave only the UPDATE part and i delete the rest, the same is returned. The UPDATE works if i run it separately though.

Comment: Where are you seeing -1? The anonymous block (not procedure) you've shown doesn't have any output; so are there debugs you haven't shown, or is your client showing it? How are you calling it? [It seems to work...](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=9d4fc67bf002b223ef508273d3f9fe42)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Sorry, first time doing this anonymous block, to test it i'm using DBeaver, and when a execute that block it gives me -1 updated rows. When i've done simple updated before it always showed a logic number.

Comment: If DBeaver is saying that then it seems to be a quirk (or bug) of that client. The updates are happening, but you can't tell how many without doing more work. The block doesn't return the number of updated rows - it doesn't return anything. It could be doing lots of different operations of different kinds, or no DML at all. You are updating two tables, so would you expect the number of `houses`, number of `ads`, or both? You could keep track of the total number of rows actually updated - look at `sql%rowcount` - and print that or extract it with a bind variable. (Also look at `forall`).

Comment: ... [a bit like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62843258/266304). I'm not sure if you actually need to know the number of rows updated in one or both tables, or if you just thought it wasn't updating anything - which it is, as you can see in the earlier db<>fiddle.

Comment: I put the counter inside the block and now i can see the number of updated rows correctly! DBeaver doesn't show this number apparently. Thank you for your time!